# Android SVG graphics - Cons of converting current PNG files to svg format

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

i seen some tools on github and now vector drawables in Lolipop allow you use svg files.  One major advantage i find is that svg files should stretch and keep proper scaling thus looking sharp after stretching. Now with svg files i can keep all my images in the drawable folder instead of filtering them out by density.  This makes the apk file smaller which is desirable.

Question:  Would there be any reason i would not want to take my current PNG images in native android project and convert them to svg files with for example an online converter tool like [vector magic](http://vectormagic.com/) ?

Comment: You can choose one of the few SVG importing libraries. There is **good** reasons to **prefer SVG** to PNG files. (vectors are scalable, so no need to have many repeated graphics in different folders)

Comment: I suppose that there'll be (sooner or later) a version of the **support library** to allow us to use the VectorDrawables on older devices, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons that you would not want to do this.

First, vector drawables are only supported on Android 5.0+. If you are only targeting Lollipop and above, this won't be an issue, but you will still need PNGs for older versions of Android.

Second, converting raster to vector will in most cases yield poor results. Instead, you should start by creating the original assets as vector images in a program like Illustrator. Then export to SVG for conversion to VectorDrawable format and export to PNG for the DPI buckets you'd like to support on pre-5.0 devices.

Comment: You can choose one of the few **SVG importing libraries**. There is good reasons to prefer SVG to PNG files. (vectors are scalable, so no need to have many repeated graphics in different folders)

Comment: This is a good point. If you don't need to reference Drawables from XML, then you could use an SVG library that supports pre-5.0 devices and use only SVG.

Comment: I suppose that there'll be (sooner or later) a version of the **support library** to allow us to use the VectorDrawables on older devices, too.

Comment: Potentially. Because Android doesn't support loading custom drawables from XML, though, it will still have the same limitation that they cannot be referenced from layout XML.